# android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException in AsyncTask's doInBackground

Tags: android, android-asynctask, networkonmainthread

Why do I get in an AsyncTask which should a android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException? I thought that an AsyncTask is the solution to that problem. The exxeption is on line 7.

```
private class ImageDownloadTask extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, byte[]> {
    @Override
    protected byte[] doInBackground(String... params) {
        try {
            URL url = new URL(params[0]);
            URLConnection connection = url.openConnection();
            InputStream inputStream = connection.getInputStream();
            ByteArrayOutputStream byteBuffer = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            int bufferSize = 1024;
            byte[] buffer = new byte[bufferSize];

            int len;
            while ((len = inputStream.read(buffer)) != -1) {
                byteBuffer.write(buffer, 0, len);
            }
            return byteBuffer.toByteArray();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            return new byte[0];
        }
    }
}
```

I want to use it for downloading a picture.

```
public byte[] getProfilePicture(Context context, String id) {
    String url = context.getString(R.string.facebook_picture_url_large, id);
    ImageDownloadTask task = new ImageDownloadTask();
    return task.doInBackground(url);
}
```

Comment: Add the code where you call the AsyncTask

Comment: possible duplicate of [android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6343166/android-os-networkonmainthreadexception)

Comment: No duplicate, because all posts are about ones that have not used a async task but I have and get the exception anyway.

Comment: You need to call .execute() on your AsyncTask in order for it to work in the background. https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html

Answer (score 16, accepted):

By calling `doInBackground()` directly, you are not actually using the AsyncTask functionality. Instead, you should call [execute()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#execute(Params...)) and then use the results by overriding the AsyncTask's [onPostExecute()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#onPostExecute(Result)) method as explained in the Usage section of that same page.

Answer (score 1):

Best way to download an image and attach it to a ImageView is passing the ImageView as the parameter in your async task and set the URL as a tag of the image view then after downloading the task in the `OnPostExecute()` set the image to the ImageView look at this example :

```
public class DownloadImagesTask extends AsyncTask<ImageView, Void, Bitmap> {

ImageView imageView = null;

@Override
protected Bitmap doInBackground(ImageView... imageViews) {
    this.imageView = imageViews[0];
    return download_Image((String)imageView.getTag());
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap result) {
    imageView.setImageBitmap(result);
}


private Bitmap download_Image(String url) {
    ...
}
```

And the Usage will be like this

```
ImageView mChart = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageview);
String URL = "http://www...someImageUrl ...";

mChart.setTag(URL);
new DownloadImageTask.execute(mChart);
```

The image will be attached automatically when done, for more memory optimization you could use `WeakReference`.

Good Luck.