# Code only saves file when executed the first time - Android

Tags: android, bitmap, filepath

I have the following method to download an image from a given URL. When I run the appropriate methods the first time, the file is saved to the sdcard. When I go to re-run these methods, and check if there is a file at the end of the given path, the image is not (i check with file.exists()), and null is returned. Any reason why this activity is going on? 
***The code specifically fails at input = url.openStream().***

```
public class DownloadAndReadImage {
    String strURL;
    int pos;
    Bitmap bitmap = null;

    // pass image url and Pos for example i:
    DownloadAndReadImage(String url,int position) {
        this.strURL = url;
        this.pos = position;
    }

    public String getBitmapLocation() {
        return "/sdcard/"+pos+".png";
    }

    public Bitmap getBitmapImage() {
        downloadBitmapImage();
        return readBitmapImage();
    }

    void downloadBitmapImage() {
        InputStream input;
        try {
            URL url = new URL (strURL);
            input = url.openStream();
            byte[] buffer = new byte[500*1024]; //or 500*1024
            OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream ("/sdcard/"+pos+".png");
            try {
                int bytesRead = 0;
                while ((bytesRead = input.read(buffer, 0, buffer.length)) >= 0) {
                    output.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
                }
            }
            finally {
                output.close();
                input.close();
                buffer = null;
            }
        }
        catch(Exception e) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }

    Bitmap readBitmapImage() {
        BitmapFactory.Options bOptions = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        bOptions.inTempStorage = new byte[16*1024*1024];

        String imageInSD = "/sdcard/"+pos+".png";

        bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imageInSD,bOptions);
        boolean exists = new File(imageInSD).exists();
        return bitmap;
    }
}
```

This is the call code:

```
   private void saveImage() {
        DownloadAndReadImage dImage = new DownloadAndReadImage(imageAddress, count);
        image = dImage.getBitmapImage();
    }
```

Here is my Async code

```
public void submitFile() {
    if(URLUtil.isValidUrl(imageAddress)) {
        new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Boolean>() {
            protected Boolean doInBackground(Void... voids) {
                boolean img = false;
                boolean youtube = false;
                HttpURLConnection connection = null;
                try {
                    URL url  = new URL(imageAddress);
                    connection = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                String contentType = connection.getHeaderField("Content-Type");
                img = contentType.startsWith("image/");
                if(img)
                    media = "image";
                if (!img) {
                    // Check host of url if youtube exists
                    Uri uri = Uri.parse(imageAddress);
                    if ("www.youtube.com".equals(uri.getHost())) {
                        media = "youtube";
                        youtube = true;
                    }
                }
                return img || youtube;
            }

            protected void onPostExecute(Boolean valid) {
                if (valid) {
                    Picasso.with(Demo.this).load(imageAddress).into(imagePreview);
                    saveImage();
                    //sendBroadcast(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_MOUNTED, Uri.parse("file://" + Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()))); //refreshes system to show saved file
                    submitted = true;
                    submit_but.setText("Encrypt");
                }
            }
        }.execute();
    }
}
```

I am using android studio. Thank you for your assistance.

Comment: Getting any exceptions?

Comment: No exceptions. I do not think the program is writing the image to memory.

Comment: Just the log instead of toast, your toast won't be shown because your trying to display it from a background thread.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try ensuring that you close your input stream as well. If this doesn't help please post the code you use to call download bitmap.

Comment: I added input.close() after output.close(), but the returning bitmap is still null.

Comment: Could you print the value of bytesRead in the loop? Also, I'm assuming you're doing these operations on a background thread? Keep in mind that you can only call start on a thread instance once.

Comment: I'm going to print the bytesRead.

Currently, saveImage() is called by an AsyncTask. Could this be the issue?

Comment: AsyncTasks can be executed many times, could you post your AsyncTask code?

Comment: I have narrowed down the issue. On the second creation of a DownloadAndReadImage, the program never goes into the method downloadBitmapImage. I do not understand why, though.

Comment: Going to need more of your code to answer that question. :)

Comment: I added my Async code.

I've noted that when I debug, my code does go into downloadBitmapImage() but never closes either output or input buffers. The code does not go into the "try" portion

Comment: I just used debug, and the code stops at input = url.openStream();

Comment: You never close your connection in the AsyncTask.

Comment: The URLconnection? That doesn't have a .close() or disconnect() method.

Comment: You're right, use the HttpURLConnection class instead, it should be what's returned from the URL granted it uses http or https.

Comment: That did not help my problem but thank you for the advice. Again, when the code reaches downloadBitmapImage() the second time around, it seems to fail at input = url.openStream(); and go straight to the next function in the calling parent.

Comment: That's consistent with getting an exception, try logging them instead of putting them in a toast and see what the log says,

Comment: On my first run, I catch a NetworkOnMainThreadException right at the location that my program fails at later.
I get the same error moments later when it fails the second time around (the issue that I wrote about). The error below my exception is: at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1147)

I thought that by setting my internet calls in an AsyncTask that would alleviate any stress on the MainNetwork? Obviously not though.

How do I address this?

Comment: ^my question has been answered multiple times on SO. Thank you JohanShogun: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26224016/android-os-networkonmainthreadexception-in-asynctasks-doinbackground

Answer (score 0):

If you are calling the function with same position again, it will keep on replacing the existing file. Try with different position. Let me know if it works out. Cheers!

Comment: Pos is time dependent. I give it new Data.getTime();