# Android, find the method that causes UI hang

Tags: android, android-debug

Sometimes scrolling my RecyclerView makes the entire UI unresponsive for a few seconds. I did use an `AsynchronousTask` to update the item and not to block `onBindViewHolder`.

Is there any way to pinpoint at what method (or code line) the application hangs?

Comment: If you can, post your code. It'll be easy to see where is the problem.

Comment: I found out the problem. I upgraded the OS to Android 7.1, and it randomly crashed instead of just stuttering. I checked the log. `android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException` exception happened in the `AsynchronousTask`'s `doInBackground()`. After searching StackOverflow, I found this [android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException in AsyncTask's doInBackground](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26224016/android-os-networkonmainthreadexception-in-asynctasks-doinbackground). The problem was that I called `doInBackground()` directly, thinking that would run the task asynchronously.

Answer (score 0):

I found out the problem. I upgraded the OS to Android 7.1, and it randomly crashed instead of just stuttering. I checked the log. android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException exception happened in the AsynchronousTask's doInBackground(). After searching StackOverflow, I found this android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException in AsyncTask's doInBackground. The problem was that I called doInBackground() directly, thinking that would run the task asynchronously. –